# magento pressing on the update button on the product page adds item instead of changing item

Tags: php, magento

Magento 1.9.3.1

After adding a product to the shopping cart I try to make changes to the order by pressing the edit link. This directs me back to the product page as it should. I make changes to this existing order and after pressing the "update cart" button on the product page I go to the shopping cart again. To my amazement I see 2 orders:

1. The order I already had
2. The new order with the changes

What I should see is a changed version of the order I already had, but with the new changes.

Can someone please help me out here ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what do you mean by order. In cart you can see products or quote.
I assume you mean product:
Then check your url links which lead you to "update page" and to cart after update. It should be the same.
Anyway I need more info to investigate problem.